# Equivalent commands for (ipfw) in OS X taken from (iptables)

Tags: macos, firewall, iptables, ttl, ipfw

I was using it on my DD-WRT router. I need to increase incoming/outgoing TTL from 1 to 128. How to use this commands in OS X using (ipfw)?

`` iptables -t mangle -I PREROUTING -i `get_wanface` -j TTL --ttl-set 128 ``

`` iptables -t mangle -I POSTROUTING -o `get_wanface` -j TTL --ttl-set 128 ``

Comment: which version of OS X? ipfw is deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

IPFW does not have any options to modify packet's TTL directly. It can match a packet that has particular TTL range, but does not have any rules to modify it. Here's complete [ipfw syntax](http://bxr.su/FreeBSD/sbin/ipfw/main.c#40).

As you can see, action list is fairly limited:
    "ACTION:    check-state | allow | count | deny | unreach{,6} CODE |\n"
    "               skipto N | {divert|tee} PORT | forward ADDR |\n"
    "               pipe N | queue N | nat N | setfib FIB | reass\n"

You could [divert](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=divert) the packet to an application and let it modify and reinject it, but that would require a custom app to do it. Sort of what `natd` does, only instead of IP addresses and ports it would change TTL.